# Pronom attaché au semi-auxiliaire dans « ne les pouvant payer »

Tags: pronoms, verbes, ordre-des-mots, infinitif

Dans *Bel-Ami* de Maupassant, chapitre 1, on trouve la phrase suivante :

> [...] « Venez-vous chez moi, joli garçon ? » mais il n'osait les suivre, **ne les pouvant payer** ; et il attendait aussi autre chose [...]

Aujourd'hui, on dirait : « ne pouvant les payer ». Le COD est directement relié à payer et non pas à pouvoir. *Je ne peux pas quoi ? Les payer.*

Cependant, on retrouve de nombreuses occurrences au cours du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle du COD devant le participe présent de *pouvoir*. (source NGram)

Qu'est-ce qui justifie que cet emploi est convenable ? Existe-t-il d'autres formes de ce genre, c'est-à-dire, le COD avant le semi-auxiliaire et non pas devant le verbe qui porte l'action ?

Comment: On ne doit pas considérer qu'il existe une relation quelconque entre « les » et « pouvant » du fait de la seule proximité des deux mots ; il n'y a **aucun lien** de prime abord et seulement une juxtaposition.

Answer (score 5):

En complément à une réponse plus précise, le propos qui suit fait abstraction de la spécificité qu'aurait le verbe *pouvoir* et de l'emploi du participe présent plutôt que d'un verbe conjugué comme support de l'infinitif. On s'intéresse plutôt directement à la présence de l'infinitif et à son impact.

---

> Mesme on a ajousté ce que je pense avoir remarqué en divers endroits,
>   qu'il n'y a point de locution qui ayt si bonne grace en toutes sortes
>   de langues, que celle que l'Usage a establie contre la Reigle, et qui
>   a comme secoué le joug de la Grammaire : En effet les Poëtes Grecs et
>   Latins en ont fait de belles figures, dont ils ornent leurs escrits,
>   comme est la synecdoche (qu'ils appellent) et plusieurs autres
>   semblables, sur quoy ce mot de Quintilien, est excellent, *aliud est
>   Latinè, aliud Grammaticè loqui*. Mais pour revenir à nostre exemple,
>   on dit tout de mesme, *il a une partie du bras cassé, il a une partie
>   de l'os rompu, il a une partie du bras emporté*, et non pas *cassée,
>   rompue*, ny *emportée*.
>
> On pourroit en rendre quelque raison, mais il seroit superflu, puis
>   qu'il est constant que l'Usage fait parler ainsi, et qu'il fait
>   plusieurs choses sans raison, et mesme contre la raison, ausquelles
>   neantmoins il faut obeir en matiere de langage.
>
> [...]
>
> On respond que tous deux sont bons, mais que si celuy-là doit estre
>   appelé le meilleur, qui est le plus en usage, *je ne le veux pas
>   faire*, sera meilleur que *je ne veux pas le faire*, parce qu'il est
>   **incomparablement plus usité**. M. Coeffeteau observoit ordinairement le
>   contraire, et mettoit le pronom auprès de l'infinitif, parce que
>   faisant profession d'une grande netteté de style, il trouvoit que la
>   construction en estoit plus nette et plus reguliere; Mais il y a plus
>   de grâce, ce me semble, en cette transposition, puis que l'Usage
>   l'authorise, suivant ce qui a été dit en la Remarque, qui a pour
>   titre, *Une partie du pain mangé*. Une des principales beautez du Grec
>   et du Latin consiste en ces transpositions, et comme elles sont fort
>   rares en notre langue, surtout en prose, elles en sont plus agréables.
>
> T.C. — Je croi que l'oreille seule décide dans toutes les façons de
>   parler pareilles à celles qui sont employées dans cette Remarque.
>   [...]
>
> [ *Remarques sur la langue françoise*, Tome 2, Claude Favre de
>   Vaugelas (1585-1650) pp. [81](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6274587h/f89.item.r), [84](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6274587h/f92.item.r=%22je%20ne%20le%20veux%20pas%20faire%22) ]

L'usage et ce qui sonne bien à l'oreille parce qu'on y est habitué varient selon les époques et jouent certainement un rôle prépondérant. Grevisse et Goosse exposent plusieurs règles et choix de ces usages en ce qui a trait à la position des pronoms. La catégorisation relève davantage du nombre de compléments exprimés et de la présence de l'infinitif et la question plus utile est qu'est-ce qui justifie qu'un emploi soit variable ou qu'on y fasse obstacle dans un cas particulier, le reste étant possible. Voici un squelette d'organisation de certains usages s'appuyant sur la présentation du *Bon usage* aux § 684, 682 (Grevisse et Goosse, 14<sup>e</sup> éd., Duculot ; le propos qui suit s'inspire de leur texte et en reproduit certaines des tournures) :

---

**A.** Si l'infinitif est précédé de *tout* ou *rien* ou d'un adverbe, le pronom complément se place ordinairement après le pronom indéfini ou l'adverbe, ou souvent devant dans l'usage littéraire, dont le caractère serait accentué si l'adverbe a plus d'une syllabe :

> En repoussant un des oreillers pour mieux m'étendre. (Flaubert)
>   Des personnes se levèrent pour le mieux voir. (Zola)
>  Il y avait
>   là de quoi me beaucoup vieillir en quelques heures. (Fromentin)

**B.** Quand le pronom est complément d'un infinitif et que l'infinitif est un complément essentiel du verbe support :

[ En ancien français le pronom se plaçait toujours devant le verbe support indépendamment du verbe ; ça se prolonge même jusqu'au 17e, d'où Vaugelas ; puis un usage se constitue... LBU § 684 H2]

1. Avec un verbe support comme **voir, entendre, écouter, faire, laisser, envoyer, regarder**, ordinairement le pronom se place **devant le verbe support** :

   *L'infinitif a un pronom complément* :

   > Si j'avais su que vous n'aviez votre soirée prise par personne, je
   >   vous aurais envoyé chercher. (Proust) [on le place devant le verbe support]

   *L'infinitif a plusieurs pronoms compléments* :

   > Il ne prononça plus qu'avec effort les dernières syllabes, et encore
   >   après se les avoir fait répéter trois fois. (Sand) [on le place devant le verbe
   >   support]

   *Le verbe support et l'infinitif ont chacun leur pronom complément* :

   > Je vous en regarde manger. (Duhamel) [on le place devant le verbe support]

   Le pronom complément de l'infinitif **ne peut** se placer devant le verbe support si :

   - Le support est à l'impératif affirmatif : *Laissez-vous conduire* (Musset) [on le place entre les deux, avec trait d'union]
   - S'il en résulte un **groupement interdit** [*me, te, se, nous, vous* ne peuvent être juxtaposés ni se joindre à *lui* ou *leur* ; le pronom objet indirect doit prendre la forme disjointe avec préposition. LBU § 682 ] :

     > Toi seule peut adoucir, par ton aveu, ce qui me fait te haïr. (Proust)
   - Avec le pronom réfléchi : *Elle verse la poésie et la beauté à tous les êtres, à toutes les plantes qu'on laisse s'y développer à souhait.* (Sand)
   - Si l'agent de l'infinitif est un nom ou un pronom autre que personnel placé avant l'infinitif : *J'ai vu sa mère le battre.* Mais on dit : *Je l'ai vu battre par sa mère.*


     Hormis ces cas on a des choix.
2. Avec des verbes différents que ceux mentionnés précédemment, l'usage ordinaire est de placer le pronom **devant l'infinitif** :

   > Il saura me comprendre.

   Il y a beaucoup de nuances, dont l'usage régional :

   > J'te vas claquer à gifles. (La Varende)

   L'usage littéraire le place parfois devant le verbe support :

   > Je n'y pouvais consentir. (de Gaulle) 
   >   J'y veux trouver des
   >   exemples. (A. Rey)
   >   Comme sa fille à elle l'allait faire.
   >   (Yourcenar)

   Et des nuances dans ces nuances.

   - L'infinitif a deux pronoms personnels compléments, ils sont presque exclusivement devant l'infinitif, mais moins si le pronom est *en* ou *y* etc.
   - Le pronom devant le verbe support représente le même être que son sujet, le pronom est alors réfléchi, le support prend l'auxiliaire être aux temps composés :

     > L'Allemagne s'est voulu venger. (Chateaubriand)
   - Il est assez rare de voir le pronom placé devant le support quand l'infinitif lui est joint par une préposition comme dans cet exemple :

     > J'en viens d'avoir l'éclaboussante certitude. (Zola)

---

En résumé, l'usage. Oui, il y plein d'exemples, certains vecteurs des possibilités ou des interdictions étant l'usage littéraire, le régionalisme, la syntaxe, la nature du pronom, la relation entre les verbes, le nombre de compléments et à quel verbe ils se rattachent.

Comment: This answer is not intended to be used as a fullproof way to ascertain pronoun position in such and such a case. It is rather a selection aimed at showcasing variation and the underlying usage.

Comment: Comment ceci pourrait n'être qu'une réponse partielle? C'est amplement suffisant pour justifier le tour. Possiblement que ça ne justifie pas suffisamment la raison de sa disparition en français moderne. Je pardonne sans problème ce défaut mineur: c'est très bien documenté. Chapeau!

Comment: « S'attarde » ? Ne voulais-tu pas dire « s'attache » plutôt ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez La réponse et/ou son auteur s'attarde, en ce sens qu'elle ou il passe du temps de ce côté de la chose à en étudier les détails. Nous avons un peu ici [*le calepin d’un flâneur*](https://www.babelio.com/livres/Leclerc-Le-calepin-dun-flaneur/47287), si j'ai bien compris.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'aurais pu le vouloir mais non c'était « se consacrer momentanément à une chose de préférence à d'autres ». Peut-être que l'adverbe _directement_ s'y rattache mal, ou s'attarder c'est davantage utilisé de manière péjorative. Pour moi attacher c'est surtout un truc concret, comme les lacets (ou à la personne), je connais moins le sens de _s'intéresser à_ etc. S'intéresser est peut-être plus clair pour tous.

Comment: Ok, à la fois la syntaxe (on emploie « s'attarder sur » par ici) et le sens, me paraissaient étrange. Donc je me demandais si c'était pas une correction automatique ratée. Mais visiblement non.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez « Toute l'après-midi, ils s'attardèrent au ménage, balayèrent, firent le lit. Lui-même avait voulu l'aider. C'était un jeu, ils s'amusaient comme des enfants rieurs. » (Zola) ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attarder)) ;-) Le sujet d'une autre question !

Comment: Oui, pour une tâche ça marche avec *à*, et historiquement je me rends compte que c'était employé aussi pour un objet d'intérêt comme dans ta phrase, mais il me semble que l'usage a changé et que *sur* l'emporte maintenant dans ce cas (hors usage littéraire) dans certaines régions (je ne saurais dire jusqu'où). Dans le TLF, l'exemple « s'attarder aux souvenirs d'enfance » me surprend mais pas les autres.