# L'emploi de « s'attarder à » signifiant « se consacrer momentanément à une chose [abstraite] de préférence à d'autres » est-il toujours vivant etc. ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, prépositions, verbes-pronominaux, connotation

Au TLFi on trouve un emploi du verbe [*attarder*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attarder) employé pronominalement :

> II. B. 2. a) **S'attarder à.**[Suivi d'un subst. ou d'un inf.] a) Se consacrer momentanément à une chose de préférence à d'autres, prendre son temps
>   pour faire quelque chose :
>
> [...]
>
> 14. Elle **s'attardait aux** souvenirs d'enfance parce qu'elle ne pouvait souffler mot de souvenirs moins lointains qui l'obsédaient. R.
>       Martin du Gard, Les Thibault, *La Mort du père*, 1929, p. 1319.
> 15. Le conteur ne dirige pas la suite des événements vers la conclusion, mais se perd en détails amusants. Un Indien des prairies
>       **s'attardera à** décrire comment on abat un bison; un indigène de l'Afrique du Sud se plaira à des détails culinaires. R.-H. Lowie,
>       *Manuel d'anthropol. culturelle*,1936, p. 224.

Quand j'[explique](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/34658/1) m'intéresser à un sujet de préférence à un autre en dissertant j'emploie ce verbe et c'est donc usuel pour moi. Mais je note ce qui semble être uniquement l'emploi péjoratif au [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_attarder/6212?q=s%20attarder#6193) et la présentation du sens au figuré est plus ou moins claire au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/attarder). D'autre part un [autre locuteur](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34632/pronom-attach%C3%A9-au-semi-auxiliaire-dans-ne-les-pouvant-payer/34658#comment71017_34658) était plus familier avec la présence de la préposition *sur* [au TLFi, **II. B. 1.** **S'attarder dans, s'attarder sur.** Prendre du retard, généralement avec complaisance, dans une entreprise] et des usages concrets avec la préposition *à*.

- L'emploi au figuré (II. B. 2. a) consistant à « se consacrer
  momentanément à une chose de préférence à d'autres » avec la chose
  abstraite est-il encore reconnu ; analyse-t-on l'action
  obligatoirement avec une connotation d'indulgence excessive ?
- Y a-t-il un glissement vers l'emploi de la préposition *sur* pour cet
  emploi le cas échéant ?

Comment: Ce n'est que mon opinion mais il me semble que tout cela va avec un changement de paradigme. Nous ne nous attardons plus à faire une tâche (manuelle, notamment) mais plus à faire de multiples tâches qui correspondent à un dossier (on travaille "sur le dossier Machin")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quelques recherches sur Gallica nous donnent de curieux résultats.

Si l’on recherche « [**s’attarder à**](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22s%27attarder%20%C3%A0%22%29&lang=en&suggest=0) », on retrouve quasi-exclusivement des emplois négatifs. On le déconseille, on l’interdit même parfois, on affirme l’inutilité ou le peu d’intérêt d’un attardement. **Sans s’attarder à** ceci. **On ne peut s’attarder à** cela. **Point besoin de s’attarder à** cette autre chose. **Inutile de s’attarder à** étudier tel item.

> 12° **Je défends** aux premiers éléments d’attaque **de s’attarder à** la capture des prisonniers, de rechercher et de dénombrer les gains, matériel, etc. Tous les éléments avancés devront progresser sans arrêt, rapidement, sans s’occuper de ce qui se passe sur leur gauche ou sur leur droite.
> <sub>—*Les armées françaises dans la Grande guerre,* par l’État-major des armées de France. Service historique (1923-1934)</sub>
>
> Au point de vue juridique, **il n’est pas besoin de s’attarder à** réfuter cette doctrine, qui n’a aucune base sérieuse.
> <sub>—*Recueil général des lois et des arrêts : en matière civile, criminelle, commerciale et de droit public*, par J.-B. Sirey (1904, Paris)</sub>
>
> Avec nos habitudes de précision nous sommes étonnés qu’en douze volumes on ait pu dire si peu de choses, mais **il faut ne pas trop s’attarder à** cette première impression. Mercier ne voulait faire ni un guide ni un dictionnaire des curiosités de Paris. L’un et l’autre existaient. Ce qu’il avait projeté, c’était une étude des mœurs parisiennes sous le règne de Louis XVI, et, aucune, dans son ensemble, n’est plus complète, plus exacte que celle-là.
> <sub>—*Au jour le jour,* par Pierre Veuillot in *L’Univers* (1914, Paris)</sub>
>
> Et **sans s’attarder à** des politesses qu’il jugeait superflues, le cousin d’Yvonne se précipita vers l’escalier qui mène à la sortie.
> <sub>—*Le cochon d’or,* par Fortuné Du Boisgobey, 1882</sub>

Par contre, en cherchant « [**s’attarde à**](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&startRecord=0&maximumRecords=15&page=1&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22s%27attarde%20%C3%A0%22%29) », on trouve assez rapidement des exemples positifs, dans lesquels l’attardement peut se montrer *charmant*, ou alors être partie nécessaire du processus d’assimilation des réalités et événements de ce monde. C’est en s’attardant que l’on découvre les détails.

On trouvera aussi qu’il n’est pas forcément malséant de s’attarder à faire des adieux, même si la situation est urgente.

> Il contera fleurette – en supposant qu’à notre époque on **s’attarde à** ce mode désuet et charmant – à une oisive qui aura besoin de lui en vue d’assurer ou d’orner son existence matérielle.
> <sub>—*La femme dans la France de demain,* Henry Spont (1917)</sub>
>
> C’est Judith ; la servante qui doit l’accompagner est au pied de la muraille et **s’attarde à** faire ses adieux à un ami.
> <sub>—*Grand dictionnaire universel du XIXe siècle (1890)*, article « Judith, tableau de M. J.-C. Cazin, exposé au Salon de 1883 »</sub>
>
> [...] Sur lui, pas de blessure,
> Rien ne l’a profané. Son regard attristé
> **S’attarde à** parcourir le temple dévasté.
> Dans le bourg, tout est mort. Ce qui créait la joie,
> Des flammes, des pillards, est devenu la proie.
> <sub>—*L’amour invincible,* Lieutenant E.G. (1916, in *Bulletin meusien*)</sub>
>
> L’on était au Croisic qui, aux jours d’août, donne l’illusion d’une côte beaucoup plus méridionale, avec l’ardeur excessive de son ciel achevant de cuire les sables d’or semés des diamants du mica, effritant les masses de granit... ces roches immenses, si pareilles à des cathédrales, écroulées, à des châteaux forts démantelés que, malgré soi, l’œil **s’attarde** à essayer de préciser en ces pierres d’anciens contours détruits.
> <sub>—*L’autel,* Camille Pert (1907, feuilleton dans *Le Journal*, Paris)</sub>
>
> Aime-t-il ce Paris dont il **s’attarde à** décrire les rues et les paysages, la rue de la Chine, l’avenue de la Motte-Picquet, ou les types comme le marchand de marrons, le conducteur d’omnibus, le peintre, la blanchisseuse, le coiffeur, ou encore les spectacles et les fêtes populaires? Assurément, il l’aime [...]
> <sub>—*Bulletin de la Société J.-K. Huysmans,* Jean Morienval (1930, Paris)</sub>

---

Rien dans l’historique de l’édition, si ce n’est un usage qui semble s’être attaché plus particulièrement à des utilisations négatives du verbe ou à la dépréciation de ceux qui s’y livrent, ne semble empêcher des formulations comme :

- On s’attardera volontiers à...
- On doit prendre le temps de s’attarder à [...] si l’on veut [...]
- Attardons-nous un instant à [...], afin de pouvoir [...]
- On se demandera avec raison si [...], et avant d’y répondre, il conviendra de se tourner vers [...] et de s’attarder à un détail dont l’importance est capitale.

---

#### Changement de paradigme ?

Par contre, ainsi que mentionné dans un commentaire sous la question, un changement de paradigme pourrait aussi être survenu, qui ait renforcé la perception négative de l’attardement. Les lexicologues, par exemple, passent certainement encore aujourd’hui bien du temps à se poser des questions sur les nuances particulières de tel ou tel terme, et y prennent sans doute un certain plaisir. Mais on dira plutôt d’eux qu’ils **s’attachent à déterminer** les nuances, plutôt que de **s’attarder à les étudier**. Ça offre une image plus dynamique et sérieuse, et affirmer que l’on travaille en utilisant judicieusement son temps est préférable que d’affirmer que l’on est payé pour s’amuser à ce qui nous passionne, et que l’on veut plus d’argent parce qu’on aime vraiment ce qu’on fait et qu’on veut continuer à s’attarder à nos petites [tétracapillectomies](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/t%C3%A9tracapillectomie.php).

De la même manière, on **prendra le temps nécessaire** pour bien cerner un concept, plutôt que de **s’attarder au** dit concept.

Ce changement de perception est fort possible.

En fait, il semble bien qu’il soit à peu près consommé dans la Francophonie en général.

Par contre, le Canada francophone, dans un surprenant mouvement à contre-courant, a semblé maintenir et même renforcer l’image d’un attardement positif. On s’y attarde plus facilement, sans qu’un quelconque aspect de culpabilité y soit intrinsèquement lié : on admet s’être attardé et ce n’est pas mal, on promet de s’attarder à quelque chose et on projette une image dynamique, on accuse des gens de ne pas le faire et la honte peut tomber sur eux, une tâche, même obligatoire, nécessite un attardement et c’est ainsi. Les exemples pleuvent. Une recherche dans les nouvelles récentes, par exemple, nous donne pour le Canada :

> [...] il est **judicieux de s’attarder à** son image de marque et à toutes les nuances qui y sont associées.
> <sub>—*Jobboom,* 17 avril 2019</sub>
>
> Gaétan Barrette a **accusé** le ministre **de ne pas s’attarder à** la collecte des données qui pourraient être partagées entre les réseaux de la Santé et de l’Éducation.
> <sub>—*Le Devoir,* 16 avril 2019</sub>
>
> Les Canadiens ne sont **pas pressés à s'attarder à** leurs impôts.
> <sub>—*La Presse,* 30 mars 2019</sub>
>
> Le golfeur canadien **a pu commencer à s'attarder à** sa semaine de travail au Augusta National.
> <sub>—*Le Journal de Montréal,* 9 avril 2019</sub>
>
> La charte, qui s’appliquera dès 2020 à tous les partenaires de la Ville, **promet** aussi **de s’attarder à** l’accessibilité universelle à proximité des chantiers.
> <sub>—*Métro Montréal,* 11 avril 2019</sub>
>
> Profitant de la salle de musique presque toujours vide de son école, le jeune Lepage s’initie au plus d’instruments possibles, et **préfère s’attarder à** la composition plutôt qu’au perfectionnement.
> <sub>—*SorsTu.ca,* 29 mars 2019</sub>
>
> <sup>**Introduisant parfois un verbe à l’infinitif, comme plus communément observé ailleurs dans la Francophonie**</sup>
> D’un autre côté, l’abcès a été crevé pour de bon devant une masse de journalistes et l’équipe – qui a obtenu une seule victoire depuis neuf matchs (1-6-2) – pourra **s’attarder à retrouver** son aplomb.
> <sub>—*RDS.ca,* 11 janvier 2019</sub>

Alors qu’en Europe, l’attardement semble moins valorisé, et bien moins utilisé. Les exemples sont plus rares, et à tendance plus généralement négative :

> Juger est son droit, mais **il ne faut pas s'attarder à** son jugement.
> <sub>—*Paris-Match Belgique,* 9 janvier 2019</sub>
>
> En revanche, « attendu qu’un produit dangereux n’est pas nécessairement défectueux », ils estiment « qu’il n’y a donc **pas lieu de s’attarder à** déterminer si le Lasso est défectueux du seul fait de sa toxicité intrinsèque ».
> <sub>—*Libération,* 11 avril 2019</sub>
>
> <sup>***Un contre-exemple, tout de même***</sup>
> Il faudrait aussi **s’attarder à** découvrir la vie de ceux qu’on appelle improprement les « liquidateurs », puisqu’ils seraient en réalité plutôt des futurs liquidés pour un bon nombre d’entre eux.
> <sub>—*Agora Vox,* 1 octobre 2013</sub>

Même son de cloche en Afrique :

> Et quand bien même, le président avait sans doute bien d’autre chose à faire ce jour-là **que de s’attarder à** bavarder avec quelques journalistes.
> <sub>—*La Libreville,* 25 mars 2019</sub>
>
> Les Sénégalais méritent mieux que de **s’attarder à** écouter ce petit monsieur avec une courte pensée, qui se croit investi d’une mission pour indiquer le chemin à suivre aux électeurs sénégalais.
> <sub>—*Ndarinfo,* 26 juillet 2018</sub>

Comment: Bon tour d'horizon. Est-ce que tu aurais par hasard trouvé des exemples récents avec *s'attarder à* + substantif, en excluant les proposition infinitives, et lorsque le substantif n'est pas une tâche (comme le *s'attarder aux souvenirs* du TLF, ou le *s’attarder à cette première impression* que tu cites, mais qui date de 1914) ? Au passage, *s'attarder à Paris* c'est un accident syntaxique, il s'agit d'un complément de lieu, pas d'un objet indirect.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je n'ai pas spécialement recherché des tournures particulières. En fait, ça ne m'a même pas effleuré l'esprit... Mais je m'y attarderai. Merci! (EDIT: il y a toujours «s’attarder à son jugement»)

Comment: Ah, oui, j'étais passé un peu trop vite sur celui-là (*son jugement*) en tentant de classifier, j'avais mal compris le sens. Par contre je vois aussi que *à* est en gras dans « s'attarder à l'envi sur », mais c'est en fait un exemple de *s'attarder sur* : *à l'envi* joue un role d'adverbe.

Comment: Combien excellent !

Answer (score 2):

Le *Grand Robert* n'indique nulle part que cette expression est désuète. Elle me semble au contraire tout à fait répandue. Par ailleurs, *Antidote 9* cite, à propos de l'expression *s'attarder à*, deux journaux (québécois) contemporains.

> Comme à son habitude, la romancière s’est attardée à décrire la vie
> dans le détail de sa quotidienneté. *Le Devoir*
>
> Le récit s’attarde ainsi à décrire les moyens radicaux que prendra la
> jeune femme pour confronter son père à la souffrance de ses proches.
> *LaPresse.ca*

Cette expression ne me semble d'ailleurs pas avoir une connotation particulièrement péjorative. Je rejoins en partie le commentaire de SteffX pour faire reposer cette interprétation sur une conception bien précise de ce que doit être le temps utile : celle selon laquelle passer du temps à faire quelque chose serait forcément négatif sur le plan de la rentabilité.

En bref : c'est une expression courante et elle n'est pas péjorative *per se*.