# Pourquoi « on le peut observer » et non « on peut l’observer »?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe, verbes-pronominaux, verbes-modaux

Dans le roman « Les faux-monnayeurs » d’André Gide, le personnage Édouard écrit dans son journal:

> La lente *décristallisation*, dont je n’entends jamais parler, est un phénomène psychologique qui m’intéresse bien davantage. J’estime qu’on le peut observer, au bout d’un temps plus ou moins long, dans les mariages d’amour.

Pourquoi le syntagme utilisé est-il « on le peut observer » et non « on peut l’observer »? L’antécédent de « le » est évidemment « un phénomène psychologique » et je crois que l’objet s’attache au verbe « observer ».

Comment: Cette [question-là](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34632) va peut-être aussi t'intéresser...

Comment: « et je crois que l'objet s'est attaché » est bizarre ; s'il ne s'agit pas d'autre chose que « et je crois que « le » est le complément d'objet du verbe « attacher »», il vaut mieux écrire quelque chose comme « et je crois que « le » est le complément d'objet du verbe « attacher »» ; sinon, c'est indéchiffrable et il faut trouver un autre moyen pour exprimer ce qui est réellement votre pensée.

Comment: Ah! Je vois tout d'un coup ; c'est « s'attache » que vous voulez dire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une syntaxe ancienne, qui aujourd'hui n'est plus utilisée, excepté dans un registre littéraire soutenu.

Cf. le point 2.c [ici](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/314.html)

Comment: +1: Tu as gagné avec 50 secondes d'avance ;-)

Answer (score 6):

La signification est la même. Il s'agit d'une forme archaïque où le pronom est placé avant le verbe. Elle ne subsiste qu'à l'écrit et dans un registre soutenu.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Les autres ont bien répondu, pour ajouter aux réponses j'aimerais juste citer le principe des paroles transposées : on peut le voir dans les pièces de Molière par exemple, notamment dans *Le bourgeois gentilhomme* avec la fameuse phrase

> Belle marquise, vos yeux me font mourir d'amour

On peut quasiment transposer n'importe quel mot avec un autre et comprendre la phrase :

- Belle marquise, d'amour mourir vos yeux me font
- Belle marquise, mourir d'amour vos yeux me font
- Belle marquise, me font mourir, d'amour vos yeux
- d'amour, belle marquise, vos yeux mourir me font
- etc.

Tout ça pour dire qu'avant, la langue française avait certaines libertés dans la construction des phrases, et que donc, si tu lis des auteurs assez vieux, tu tomberas souvent sur des tournures un peu tordues comme ça.

Comment: Ah oui, je viens de finir « Les nourritures terrestres » de Gide, qui contient beaucoup de transpositions syntactiques.

Answer (score 3):

En guise de réponse, quelques informations historiques sur les deux constructions concurrentes tirées de *Sociolinguistic Variation in Seventeenth-Century France* de Wendy Ayres-Bennet et de *L'évolution de l'ordre des mots dans la phrase française de 1600 à 1700* d'Yvette Galet.

En ancien français, seule la construction pronom + verbe fini + infinitif (*on le peut observer*) est attestée.  Au 16e siècle, c'est cette construction qui prévaut.  Si l'on exclut les cas où l'ordre des mots est influencé par la versification, elle est employée dans 88% des constructions possibles par Rabelais dans *Pantagruel* (1532), 100% par Du Bellay dans *Les Regrets* (1558), 82% par Montaigne dans les *Essais* (1572 - 1587) et 77% par Régnier dans les *Satyres* (1603 - 1613).

La construction moderne, verbe fini + pronom + infinitif (*on peut l'observer*), s'impose au cours du 17e siècle avec des variations d'un auteur à l'autre et, pour un même auteur, d'une œuvre à l'autre.

La Fontaine, dont la langue est conservatrice, utilise presque également les deux constructions dans les années 1670, intense période de création chez lui.  Molière semble préférer la construction moderne à partir de 1661.  Le recours par Bossuet à la construction ancienne est peu élevé entre 1661 et 1670 (à peu près 30%) mais on la trouve dans 52% des cas dans l'oraison funèbre de Marie-Thérèse d'Autriche (1683).

Les œuvres de Corneille, né en 1606, sont particulièrement significatives.  On constate un renversement dans son usage en 1643.  Jusque-là l'ancienne construction domine, à partir de 1643, il lui préfère la moderne.  Dans sa dernière pièce, *Suréna*, l'ordre ancien représente 33% des cas possibles.  Il est intéressant de voir qu'à partir de 1660 Corneille révise ses pièces et remplace notamment la construction ancienne par la nouvelle, ce qui donne à penser que l'ordre ancien était à ce moment-là considéré comme un archaïsme.

Answer (score 0):

Some stylistic reasons can be given.

(1) Lets admit that the verb is " pouvoir observer" . Putting the direct object complement before the the verb creates an equilibrium in the sentence, for the circumstantial complement ( after the verb) is very long. So the construction

```
       Subject + Direct object ("le") + Verb + Circumstantial completement
```

allows to counterbalance the circumstantial complement.

(2) Second reason: if the writer had chosen this sentence construction  :

"J’estime qu’on  peut l'observer, au bout d’un temps plus ou moins long, dans les mariages d’amour"

the stress had been put  on the circumstantial complement, I mean that the sentence could have been read as an answer to the question : " In what circumstances can this phenomenon be observed". And in that case, the answer could have benn interpreted as " it is not observed in all circumstances, but only sometimes, in certain special circumstances."

So the first construction tends to reduce the importance or the reality of the phenomenon. But this goes in a  direction exactly opposite to  the author's intentions.

What the writer aimed at was to emphasize the importance or reality of the phenomenon.

The question the writer wanted to answer was : " Is this phenomenon really observable ? ". And he wanted to stress the actual observability ( and therefore , reality) of the phenomenon.

Answer : " oui, on le peut observer" ( oui, il est effectivement observable)

With the second construction ( actually chosen), the circumstantial complement appears as a simple concession: the fact that the phenomenon is observable specially in these circumstances changes nothing to the fact that " on le peut observer".